# bash case-insensitive commands matching

Tags: bash, command-line, case-sensitivity

Is it possible for bash to find commands in a case-insensitive way?

eg. these command lines will always run python:

```
python
Python
PYTHON
pyThoN
```

Comment: 2^6 aliases for python.  2^4 for bash.  2^(len(filename)) for how many other programs?  and then copy those aliases to every other system you use.  I recommend just accepting the fact that unix filesystems are case-sensitive and learning to type (with tab-completion) the correct command name.  some things aren't problems and don't need to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `alias` shell builtin, for example:

```
alias Python='python'
alias PYTHON='python'
alias Python='python'
alias pyThoN='python'
```

For a better approach, the `command_not_found_handle()` function can be used as described in this post: [regex in alias](https://superuser.com/questions/834859/can-we-use-regex-in-alias-command).
For instance, this will force all the commands to lowercase:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    LOWERCASE_CMD=$(echo "$1" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
    shift
    command -p $LOWERCASE_CMD "$@"
    return $?
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work with builtin commands like `cd`.

Also (if you have Bash 4.0) you can add a tiny function in your `.bashrc` to convert uppercase commands to lowercase before
executing them. Something similar to this:

```
function :() {
    "${1,,}"
}
```

Then you can run the command by calling `: Python` in command line.

NB as @cas mentioned in the comments, : is a reserved bash word. So to avoid inconsistencies and issues you can replace it with `c` or something not already reserved.

Comment: interesting, so i could make a `command_not_found_handle()` function that convert the command to lowercase.

Comment: update: it works, but not with bultin commands like `cd`... btw still better than defining a lot of aliases...

Comment: See my updated answer. It might be something useful.

Comment: `:` is a shell builtin, the null statement.  It does nothing, and does so quite deliberately.  It's useful as a placeholder in, e.g., `if` and similar statements:  `if something; then : else  echo something ; fi`, which would otherwise be a syntax error.  see `man bash` and search for ` : ` (space,colon,space).

Comment: Yes I know. I just wanted to have the shortest possible function name. Something else can be used instead.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The tiny function solution does not look very user-friendly to me, i like the one based on the `command_not_found_handle()` function much more. Can i add the code for it in your answer?

Comment: Yes feel free to do so! :-)

Comment: Since this will work for commands which are originally in lowercase, it will fail for such (never seen, but not prohibited) in all UPPERCASE, Capitalized or CamelCase. Another, approach, excessive if you strive for completeness, would be, to create symbolic links to all programs. It's just theoretically doable and will fail for reserved words like IF, WHILE, FOR and so on and for parameters. So the user has to know the restrictions very well, to gain advantages from such interventions. It will be much more easy to learn, that almost all programs are all lowercase.